# Passing lambda as an argument in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, lambda

I'm using Kotlin and I'm trying to pass a lambda as a function parameter

```
var lambda = {existingEntity: SomeEntity?, param1: String? -> {
        val test = someFunction(existingEntity)
        existingEntity?.copy(name = param1)!!
     }}

    fun updateValue(param2: UUID, param1: String? = null): Mono<Boolean> {
        return updateFunc(param2, param1, lambda)
    }

    private fun updateFunc(param2: UUID, param1: String?, lambda: (SomeEntity?, String?) -> () -> SomeEntity): Mono<Boolean>{
        return repository.findById(param2)
            .flatMap {
                val existingEntity = it
                repository.update(existingEntity, lambda(it, param1))
                    .map { true }
            }
    }
```

Basically I want the lambda to return type `SomeEntity`. With the above implementation, the lambda returns `() -> SomeEntity` instead of `SomeEntity`. This causes an issue while calling `repository.update()`.

How do I write the lambda to return `SomeEntity`  instead of `() -> SomeEntity` ?

Comment: Remove _-> ()_?

Comment: I didn't get exactly what to remove. Could you please point it out?

Comment: If I remove that from updateFunc() it throws an error in updateValue() as follows Required:
(ListEntity?, String?) → ListEntity
Found:
(ListEntity?, String?) → () → ListEntity

Comment: And in the var _lambda_ remove the {} in the lambda itself (you have a lambda nested in the lambda). So that it is like this: _... param1: String? -> val test = ... }_

Comment: removing the extra {} worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you wrap a fragment of code into `{}` you are getting a lambda. For example:

```
val v = "I am a value!" // String

val v = {
    "I am a function!"
} // () -> String
```

So...

```
val lambda: (SomeEntity?, String?) -> SomeEntity = { existingEntity: SomeEntity?, param1: String? ->
    val test = someFunction(existingEntity)
    existingEntity?.copy(name = param1)!!
}
```

As you can see what I did was removing the `{}` braces inside a lambda.